# Return json in index action but not let the people access the route in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a rails application, both front and back. The front has some React components that fetch data. Is this case it fetch the comments of a blog. But on the application you can also go to `/blogs/3/comments` which is not what I want. I don't want people accessing `/blogs/3/comments` but I want the endpoint to exist.

`routes.rb`

```
  resources :blogs do
    resources :comments, only: [:show, :index]
  end
```

In the `comment_controller.rb` I have

```
  def index
    blog = Blog.find(params[:blog_id])
    @comments = blog.comments.select("comments.*, users.name").joins(:user)
    render json: { comments: @comments }
  end
```

When I do a get request with fetch or axios to get the comments of a blog it returns me the json successfully but in the website the user can also go to `/blogs/3/comments` and it will show the json.

```
{"comments":[{"id":3,"content":"lorem ...","created_at":"2020-09-11T01:55:56.281Z","updated_at":"2020-09-11T01:55:56.281Z","blog_id":3,"user_id":1,"name":"user1"},{"id":2,"content":"lorem ...s","created_at":"2020-09-11T01:55:56.262Z","updated_at":"2020-09-11T01:55:56.262Z","blog_id":3,"user_id":1,"name":"user2"},{"id":1,"content":"lorem ...","created_at":"2020-09-11T01:55:56.240Z","updated_at":"2020-09-11T01:55:56.240Z","blog_id":3,"user_id":1,"name":"user1"}]}
```

Is there a way to not let the user access `/blogs/3/comments`? And let the endpoint working for get request from other clients?

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you mean you don't want the endpoint to be accessible to text/html requests.

```
def index
 blog = Blog.find(params[:blog_id])
 @comments = blog.comments.select("comments.*, users.name").joins(:user)
 respond_to do |format|
   format.json { render json: { comments: @comments } }
   format.html { redirect_to '/somewhere_else', status: :not_acceptable }
 end
end
```

See [ActionController::MimeResponds](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/MimeResponds.html).